# how to speed up ajax calls to fetch record from php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

i'm trying to send ajax call to php file which return 1000 record at a time in json encoded format which i am appending in table. everything working fine but it takes alot for time which result in hanging of page. below is my js code.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 31; i++)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "filters.php",
            data: {limit: 1000, start_from: (i * 1000)},
            success: function(response) {
                var array = JSON.parse(response);

                Object.keys(array).forEach(function(key) {
                    oTable.fnAddData([
                        array[key][1],
                        array[key][2],
                        array[key][3],
                        array[key][4],
                        array[key][5],
                        array[key][6],
                        array[key][7],
                        array[key][8],
                        array[key][9],
                        array[key][10],
                        array[key][11],
                        array[key][12],
                        array[key][13],
                        array[key][14],
                        array[key]['link']
                    ]);
                });
            },
            datatype: 'json'
        });
    }    
});
```

Comment: Try: `oTable.fnAddData([...], false);` then after each loop call `oTable.fnDraw();`  This would avoid redrawing the table 31 * 1000 times but 31 times. But better would be to filter out all these ajax called and redraw the table only once, e.g, using `$.ajaxStop()` method

Comment: Well, first you need to identify what it is that is slow. My guess is the requests, but that `fnAddData` method looks suspicious as well. You should use `console.profile` (and `console.profileEnd`) to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Can we see your fnAddData function and your SQL?

Comment: @Jezzabeanz I guess this is datatable plugin: http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnAddData

Comment: @Jezzabeanz yes its datatable plugin function which append new rows to table.

Comment: Fair enough, though seeing what's happening on filters.php might help

Comment: its fetching records from database 1000 each time a call was send to it and return json encoded data.

Comment: @A Wolff I didn't understand your solution. Can you provide any example or code..? thanks

Comment: Check the DOC, all is explains: `Object.keys(array).forEach(function(key) {
                    oTable.fnAddData([...], false);});  oTable.fnDraw();`  Now i'm not a datatable expert but i guess you'd have better to use the pagination and only display relevant data, not 31000 rows at once

Comment: @A.Wolff i followed your instruction and its working now. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 31; i++)
    {
        setTimeout(500,function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "filters.php",
                data: {limit: 1000, start_from: (i * 1000)},
                success: function(response) {
                    var array = JSON.parse(response);

                    Object.keys(array).forEach(function(key) {
                        oTable.fnAddData([
                            array[key][1],
                            array[key][2],
                            array[key][3],
                            array[key][4],
                            array[key][5],
                            array[key][6],
                            array[key][7],
                            array[key][8],
                            array[key][9],
                            array[key][10],
                            array[key][11],
                            array[key][12],
                            array[key][13],
                            array[key][14],
                            array[key]['link']
                        ]);
                    });
                },
                datatype: 'json'
            });
        });
    }
    });
```

Comment: Speeding it up by setting a half second delay? What have you been smoking?

Comment: tried for code Babak, code inside setTimeout is not executing now. i mean it is not sending any ajax call after trying your code..

Comment: Sorry my bad.. misunderstood ur question.